# Check if a competitor is bidding on a brand term (AdWords)

Tags: google-ads

Is there a way to check on a global and regional basis for competitors bidding on a brand term in Google AdWords? I can check this manually in the 'Ad preview and diagnosis' section however i'd have to check each country one by one.

I need a way to automate this and ideally send me an alert when someone begins targeting our brand term regardless of the targeted country (we're a global company).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with 100% reliability, but there are some third party services like SpyFu which can give you that information with varying degrees of accuracy.

In my experience, the data they provide only approaches accuracy with extremely big players. With smaller campaigns/purchasers, YMMV.